# Basic text formatting in visual studio comments?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, formatting, richtext

For decades c, c++ c# comments have been plain ASCII text.

Is there any way to do basic Rich Text style comments in c#? Just simple stuff like bullet points or numbered points, bold, italics and indents, nothing more. It would make my commenting much easier to read. Seems like the world moved on from basic ASCII, but the c# comments were left behind

Comment: See `BetterComments` extension. Though I have not used it. But take a look at it. It provides colors also.

Comment: I did look at that, but it is just color and font type, and strike through. If I could just have one thing, it would be a numbered lists. Then when I write my notes and constraints and inputs etc they would all be numbered and the writing line up properly, and dang it would be easier to read

Comment: Comments cannot by itself be bold, italics etc. They are just text (and in C# by the way - unicode and not plain ASCII). Your _editor_ can interpret certain sequences in special way and display them differently (say - show sentences surrounded by "**" as bold).

Comment: Yes, it would be great if my Visual Studio Editor just natively let me do comments with numbered lists, bullets and indents. It could probably do it behind the scenes using HTML tags or something, so the actual c file (which is just text) would look like normal code but HTML bits in the comments, no one would see it - it  must be 20 years since I opened code using a txt editor, (not Visual Studio editor). Funny that no one has really asked for such a feature. We use basic bullets, indents bold in emails, MS Word and every other form of human written English. Why cant a comment be the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the C# comments are just a plain text. If you want to use any formatting, you must encode it somehow (markdown, prefix, XML tags) and use some extension to show it formatted in Visual Studio.

I don't know if you need the formatting just for you while reading your source code or also for documentation generated out of the comments. For the latter case, there is a standard way available - XML comments. Use the [<list>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/xmldoc/list) for bullet and numbered lists.

Of course, you don't see formatted text directly in VS. However, you can preview or edit such a comment in VS with [WYSIWYG comment editor](https://www.helixoft.com/vsdocman/commenting.html#editor) included in VSdocman (I'm the author of this extension).